# How to avoid starting the activity at the first tab in a TabActivity?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

i want to avoid starting activity in the first tab .. tabHost.setCurrentTab(1). When the tab activity starts, I expect that only the activity in tab 2 gets started. But, currently, Android starts both activity in tab 1 and activity in tab 2, if I set tab 2 as default current  tab

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class sample1 extends TabActivity {
    String postContent;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  

        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        postContent = bundle.getString("url");
             Log.d("securl1",postContent);
        Resources ressources = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

        // Android tab


        // Apple tab
        Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, AppleActivity.class);
        intentApple.putExtra("url", postContent);
        TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Apple")
            .setIndicator("Web")
            .setContent(intentApple);

        // Windows tab
        Intent intentWindows = new Intent().setClass(this, WindowsActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecWindows = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Windows")
            .setIndicator("Smart")
            .setContent(intentWindows);

        // Blackberry tab
        Intent intentBerry = new Intent().setClass(this, BlackBerryActivity.class);
        intentBerry .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        TabSpec tabSpecBerry = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Berry")
            .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_share_holo_dark))
            .setContent(intentBerry);


        Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, AndroidActivity.class);
        intentAndroid .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Android")
            .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_back))

            .setContent(intentAndroid);


        Intent intentBerry1 = new Intent().setClass(this, BlackBerryActivity1.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecBerry1 = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Berry")
            .setIndicator("berry")
            .setContent(intentBerry1);

        // add all tabs 
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecWindows);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecBerry);

        //set Windows tab as default (zero based)
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is really bad pratcice to user deprecated methods. Are u sure, that this is neccessary? Why u didnt use viewpager and fragments?

Comment: as `TabActivity` is deprecated u should use [actionbar with tab navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

Comment: in action bar tabs ...we cant able to set the current tab... so i used tabhost ...... here we can set the current tab ....pls give some other idea

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setEnabled(false);
```

hope it will work for you. :)

Comment: Does not work. You can only call this after you added a tab to TabHost. onCreate of the first tab will run right after you add it.